# Google maps API V3 response language is wrong for city name

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement the google maps API. All is working well except for the response which is coming back from google. The response translates the city name to my locale language (NL) but leaves the country in the desired language (EN).

Both the map and the autocomplete are displaying EN names of cities. However when clicking on a suggestion the input get's changed in just a fraction of a second to the NL variant (again leaving the country name in EN)

**Here is the script tag that I am currently using:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en&key=MYKEY'></script>
```

**The current output I get:**

```
addressLine1:"14 Bisschopsstraat"
addressLine2:""
city:"Brussel"
country:"Belgium"
country_short:"BE"
postalCode:"1000"
stateOrProvince:"Brussel"
streetName:"Bisschopsstraat"
streetNumber:"14"
```

**I have tried:**

- Adding a `region=GB` to the script tag src query but that just influences the search area priorities
- Reading all the documentation (there is not that much on how to change the language of the response though)

**Examples of what is wrong with the response:**

> Brussel *should be* Brussels
>
> Antwerpen *should be* Antwerp

[image: Autocomplete example]

Comment: (Funny, I live very close to that address.)   What exactly do you expect to happen?  Do you only want the city name in English?  Because the street name over there only exists in Dutch & French.  I don't think Google has any list of street names translated to english

Comment: :D haha And well I expect the name of the city to be in English (street names are irrelevant). So it should say Brussels in stead of Brussel and Antwerp in stead of Antwerpen :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use geocoding or places service this seems to be the intended behavior.

Please have a look at this post:
http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2014/11/localization-of-street-addresses-in.html

> Street-level addresses returned by the Google Maps Geocoding API now favor the local language, while keeping the address understandable as much as possible for both a user who only reads the requested language as well as locals.
>
> If the local language and user language both use the same alphabet, the Geocoding API will now return the local names for the streets and localities. For example, searching for an address in Brazil with user language set to English now returns “Avenida Paulista” rather than “Paulista Avenue”.

The workaround I can think about is the following:

1. You get a place ID from autocomplete element
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Bisschopsstraat%2014%2C%20Brussels%2C%20Belgium&key=YOUR_API_KEY
   This returns place ID EiVCaXNzY2hvcHNzdHJhYXQgMTQsIEJydXNzZWxzLCBCZWxnaXVt
2. You execute place details request to get latitude and longitude
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=EiVCaXNzY2hvcHNzdHJhYXQgMTQsIEJydXNzZWxzLCBCZWxnaXVt&key=YOUR_API_KEY This will return 50.8503548,4.351704499999999
3. Execute reverse geocoding for latitude,longitude specifying result type as locality and language as English
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=50.8503548%2C4.351704499999999&language=en&result_type=locality&key=YOUR_API_KEY And here you have  `"formatted_address":"Brussels, Belgium"`

Comment: Indeed, I have been over this article already but is there no way for the city names to be displayed in a specific language (street address is irrelevant in my case). The thing is that the map itself shows the correct name however when trying to capture the address it changes it to the Dutch variant :/

Comment: As far as I can see option 3 will be the most useful to me! I will implement these changes on Monday. Thank you for your time and effort! I will post an update on Monday evening!

Comment: Quite the work around but it works. I used suggested solution nr 3! Thanks!

Comment: It is not the general solution. For instance, I am retrieving address from Google Map pin by location. If I indicate result_type=locality, the city name is in the asked language, but... postal zip is not returned!! Actually, a lot of information is missing with this type which might be required. Google is weird.